# How to use math functions with gdb

Tags: c, gdb, math.h

I am a student and  I faced a problem: When I use `pow` or `asin` in my Linux programs and try to debug it with GDB I get the error: undefined reference to 'pow'.

I know that to fix this in the GCC compiler, I need to add the `-lm` key. Is there some key like `-lm` for GDB?

Comment: That sounds odd. Shouldn't need to do anything special to run in gdb. Can you please provide complete logs of the compilation and gdb run?

Comment: What makes you think that you should use GDB with some key like `-lm`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the math function, you have to compile the source code with `-lm` option (this will remove the undefined reference error for math functions),
and for making debugging symbols available in gdb, you have to compile source code with `-g` option.

`gcc -g -o myprog main.c -lm`

To debug the program run this with

`gdb ./myprog`

To print or use any function during debugging with gdb, use `call` function of gdb

`call (double)pow(3.0, 2.0)`

Make sure to use the correct syntax of function, otherwise gdb return wrong answers

`call (double) pow (double , double)`

Comment: Maybe you know how to make it work in vs code?

Answer (score 0):

gdb uses compiled file to debug. So after using -lm and -g, you can run the resulting file normally using gdb. In other words, you should be running the following which works for me:

```
gcc -g test.c -lm
gdb ./a.out
```